# Hardware optimized stream ciphers?

Tags: aes, stream-cipher, chacha, optimization

As I understand it, ChaCha20 is slower than AES-CTR in hardware.  Are there any hardware-optimized stream ciphers?

Comment: Generally stream ciphers are used when hardware based encryption is not available. Stream ciphers may have a large(-ish) state, which makes them less advantageous for hardware implementations. According to Wikipedia (about the eSTREAM competition): "but was not advanced to Phase 3 for Profile 2 because eSTREAM felt that it was probably not a good candidate for extremely resource constrained hardware environments.".

Comment: That same page mentions Grain, MICKEY and Trivium as candidates for hardware implementations. Note that these stream ciphers are almost 10 years old (and commercial crypto is around for less than 50 years).

Comment: How about AES-CTR? But yes, [the eSTREAM portfolio](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/) has three hardware ciphers. Note that the eSTREAM portfolio version is Salsa20/12. So similarly ChaCha12 might be the one to compare to AES-256, if interested in speed.

Answer (score 3):

eSTREAM competition has 2 profile:software and hardware,and the goal of hardware profile was to design a stream cipher that it should be hardware-optimized,and the final candidates were [grain v1](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/e2-grain.html) and [Trivium](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/e2-trivium.html) and [MICKEY v2](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/e2-mickey.html).a comparison of hardware performance of Grain,trivium and MICHEY is on the below image:

[image]